# How to make it so that the user cannot modify the sqlite3 database when distributing

Tags: python, sqlite, package, pyinstaller, software-distribution

I have created a python script that uses a database, which I have to pass in the file when compiling the .exe to a file. I would like to know if it is possible that the user to whom I give the file cannot edit the database (in a simple way)

[image]

I would like the file to be uneditable

Comment: Would you like to make the `.db` file uneditable ?

Comment: Yes, I would like that when distributing it it could not be edited

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to encrypt the file using a module like [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/).
But a determined attacker will always manage to find the encryption key in the executable (and this would probably cause some problems in the code)

To my knowledge, it is not possible to make a local file completely uneditable

Answer (score 0):

SQLite provides encryption functionality by itself. But it need some extra licence.

You can check the wiki: https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/release/www/readme.wiki
If you can protect the encryption key,  you will be able to protect the db file.
In the past, I've ever use the SEE integrated with sqlite. It's helpful in device application when shipping the app with data.

If you want to customize the encryption yourself, yes,  you can check some opensource cryptography library to integrate it.

Comment: Oh I had no idea about this, I think this will be my way forward, thanks a lot!